# ZF: query error SQLSTATE[HY093]

Tags: php, zend-framework, pdo, fetch

I have error on this function:

```
public function getCountCategoryByUrl($url, $root = 0)
{
    $url = strtolower($url);


    $select = $this->select()
                   ->from($this->_name, array('count(*) as cnt'))
                   ->where("LOWER(catalog_url) LIKE :url " . ($root > 0 ? " AND `type` = :type" : ""));

    return $this->getAdapter()->fetchOne($select, array('url' => $url, 'type' => $root));
}
```

Error:

```
Message: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: can you do `die($select)` before you do fetch get the result? it helps i debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem arises when you have `$root <= 0`. In this case your SQL statement contains only one token (`:url`) while you're binding two variables (`:url` **and** `:type`).

You have to set the bound parameters conditionally:

```
$select = $this->select()
               ->from($this->_name, array('count(*) as cnt'))
               ->where("LOWER(catalog_url) LIKE :url ");
$params = array(':url' => $url);
if ($root > 0) {
    $select->where("`type` = :type");
    $params[':type'] = $root;
}

return $this->getAdapter()->fetchOne($select, $params);
```

**EDIT:** I've overlooked something very important. Variables must be bound with the same token as defined in the SQL statement. This means that you have to use `:url` and `:type` for the bound variables (not `url` and `type`).

Comment: Thank you for answer. 
I tried this also. The same error:( 
I tried to remove condition aslo:

if ($root > 0) {
    $select->where("`type` = :type");
    $params['type'] = $root;
}

And I get this error again...

Comment: Please do a `echo $select->__toString();` to check what the SQL statement looks like.

Comment: I tried 2 ways - :url with quotes and without. Result the same.
SELECT count(*) AS `cnt` FROM `tbl_yaca_directories` WHERE (LOWER(catalog_url) LIKE ':url' )

Comment: My bad... I've overlooked an important issue. Edited my post.

Comment: Thanks! You are right. It works for me on local server but it doesn't work on live server. That is strange...if I do fetchOne('full query') it works perfect. What's the difference could be then?
I catched this several minutes ago...

Comment: Perhaps you should try to use the `?`-parameter notation. Use `?` instead of `:url` and `:type` and don't use an associative array for the bound variables.

Comment: On server 5.2.13. 
On local server 5.3.6
thinking of php downgrade on local machine...

Comment: Don't know of any problems with the `:`-syntax... Strange.

Answer (score 0):

Else, you can do `die($select)` to view what SQL statement is generated.

Comment: I know the problem is around the bind, but I don't know where exactly:(.
I tried to print select:
SELECT count(*) AS `cnt` FROM `tbl_yaca_directories` WHERE (LOWER(catalog_url) LIKE :url )

but it doesn't make clear what's happen...